# Flutter async stuttering with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, statefulwidget

So i'm trying to make a Voronoi Diagram application using image library. So this algoritm is quite slow, so when the button is pressed I want my not to stutter and show CircularProgressindicator, and then when computions are finished and Image is ready I want to see the image from Uint8List

```
class _VoronoiPageState extends State<VoronoiPage> {

  final TextEditingController textEditingControllerWidth = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textEditingControllerHeight = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController textEditingControllerStations = TextEditingController();
  Future<Uint8List> ?diagramImage;
  

  Uint8List createDiagram() {
    
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    int basedStation = 0;
    setState(() {
    width = int.tryParse(textEditingControllerWidth.text) ?? 0;
    height = int.tryParse(textEditingControllerHeight.text) ?? 0;
    basedStation = int.tryParse(textEditingControllerStations.text) ?? 0;
    });
    
    // Creating new image
    img.Image diagram = img.Image(width: width, height: height);
    print('image created');
    List<DrawPixels> baseStationList = generatePixels(basedStation, width, height);
    for (var pixel in baseStationList) {
      pixel.color = generateRandomColor();
    }
    // Drawingf the diagram
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        double minDistance = double.infinity;
        int minIndex = -1;
        for (int k = 0; k < basedStation; k++) {
          double distance = calculateDistance(i, j, baseStationList[k].x, baseStationList[k].y);
          if (distance < minDistance) {
            minDistance = distance;
            minIndex = k;
          }
        }
        img.drawPixel(diagram, i, j, baseStationList[minIndex].color);
      }
    }

    for (var pixel in baseStationList) {
      img.fillCircle(diagram, x: pixel.x, y: pixel.y, radius: 3, color: img.ColorFloat16.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
    return img.encodePng(diagram); 
  }
  Future<Uint8List> drawDiagram() async {
    try {
    final data = await Future.value(createDiagram());
    return data;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('pizdec');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Voronoi Diagram'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: diagramImage,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Uint8List> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
                  return const Icon(Icons.image, );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  print('connection state waiting');
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
                print('begin');
                return Image.memory(snapshot.data!);
              },
            ),
            MyTextField(
              hintText: 'Enter width', 
              textEditingController: textEditingControllerWidth,
            ),
            MyTextField(
              hintText: 'Enter heigth', 
              textEditingController: textEditingControllerHeight,
            ),
            MyTextField(
              hintText: 'Enter amount of stations', 
              textEditingController: textEditingControllerStations,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
               diagramImage = drawDiagram();
              },
              child: const Text('Create diagram'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using FutureBuilder, but somehow connectionState = ConnectionState.waiting is showing only when everything is ready, so my app is just stuttering until all computions are done.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the setState inside the function, but you need to rebuild the app when click the button.

Edit 2: Based on your project at GB, change your drawDiagrama function to

```
Future<void> drawDiagram() async {
    setState(() {
      diagramImage = null;
    });
    final data = await compute(createDiagram, [width, height, basedStation]);
    setState(() {
      diagramImage = Future.value(data);
    });
}
```

Edit 2:

Change the if inside your FutureBuilder to

```
if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
  print('connection state waiting');
  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
}
if (snapshot.hasData == false) {
  return const Icon(
    Icons.image,
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Moving setState from function to the button is a better option, but it still doesn't fix the stuttering. I found out about isolates and compute function, most likely I shlould use them for this long computions, but I don't know how to implement them properly

Comment: I was looking deep your code, so I did a little change.
Try again pls.

Comment: I finally implemented the compute function instead of simple async and it works just fine, but only on native platforms like windows, in Chrome it still stutters. And I still have a problem with CircularProgressIndicator in FutureBuilder, it doesn't show up until the very end. You can see full code on https://github.com/vladsodev/voronoi-app

Comment: Oh. I see.
You are calling the CircularProgressIndicator when is waiting, but that work like you want to. Change the if to (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) and set your diagramImage = null; before call the new value and that will work. I will put a example in my answer!

Comment: PS: put your CircularProgressIndicator() in a Center widget or it will get the SizedBox height!

Comment: Thank you! Putting null in diagramImage inside button works just find!

Comment: Nice.
If you want to use the waiting correctly, you need to wait the function in your future variable.

Ex: Future<void> drawDiagram() async {
    diagramImage = createDiagram([width, height, basedStation]);
 }

and change the createDiagram to

Future<Uint8List> createDiagram(List<dynamic> params) async {
  // await to see the loading in the screen
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
...
}
now your if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) will work fines.

Comment: I put CircularProgressIndicator() in a Center but it still takes this goofy SizedBox height :D

Comment: Just to finish:
Your function is getting the computed value, so the future is not passing to the futurebuilder, cause you are receiving the result, and not the future function.
So, if you change like I said above, it will works well.

Comment: about the CircularProgressIndicator, put in a center should works, I did a clone here and is working.  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      print('connection state waiting');
                      return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }

Comment: I tried your suggestion above and app again stutters and doesnt show indicator. Guess i'll move on with compute, thank you!

Comment: Uhh sorry it's my adhd, got it! Again, thanks a lot!